# Can I create a Virtualenv that Anaconda has nothing to do with while having Anaconda installed on my PC

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

After installing Anaconda. I created several new virtual environments and all of them had packages preinstalled that come with Anaconda. Is this normal and how can I prevent this?

Installing Anaconda causes an error while importing sklearn that is removed as soon as Anaconda is uninstalled. I want to take advantage of Anaconda(use spyder) but also create a virtual env which only installs packages by pip and does not look for those packages through anaconda when I import them(to solve the sklearn problem). In other words I want a virtual env that has nothing to do with Anaconda while having Anaconda installed on my System(windows). Is this possible?

Comment: _I created several new virtual environments and all of them had packages preinstalled that come with Anaconda._ Which packages? _Installing Anaconda causes an error while importing sklearn that is removed as soon as Anaconda is uninstalled._ What error, and where?

Comment: I have Anaconda installed and I deactivate it when I don't need it: `conda deactivate`, then `python3 -m venv .venv`, `. .venv/bin/activate`, `pip install thepackage(s)`

Comment: if reason to use anaconda is just spyder then you can install spyder in your system alone and add python interpreter there